# Regex: Match everything except backreference

Tags: regex, grep

I have the following example lines:

```
a_a
b_c
```

How (using `grep`/`egrep`) would I match the lines where the first letter is not equal to the last letter? I have tried the following but this does not seem to work correctly.

```
egrep ([ab])_[^\1]
```

Working with `egrep -v` or the inverse regex, (match everything except where first letter equals last letter), is **not possible** for my use case.

Comment: [`(?![ab])_`](https://regex101.com/r/hU8sW7/1)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use group matches.

There you create a group with the 1st character, and then put group (`\1`) at the end.

[`^(.).*\1$`](https://regex101.com/r/dZ4kB6/1)

```
egrep '^(.).*\1$'
```

Opposite:

[`^(.).*((?!\1).)+$`](https://regex101.com/r/dZ4kB6/3)

```
pcregrep '^(.).*((?!\1).)+$'
```

Comment: I'm trying to achieve the exact opposite of this, without using egrep -v.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are looking for this:

> \b([a-z])\w+(?!(\1))([a-z])\b

it works for:

a_a  and  b_c

*(tested with: The Regulator 2.0.3)*

You can then adjust this regex to meet further your needs

Comment: In this case we negate the first group which contain the first letter

Answer (score 0):

Use a negative look behind anchored to end of input. A general regex for "first char is not last char" is:

```
^(.).*(?<!\1)$
```

To match only your type of input:

```
^(.)_.(?<!\1)$
```

Comment: can you specify which regex flavor supports this? gives me `Variable length lookbehind not implemented` when I tried with `perl -ne 'print if /^(.).*(?<!\1)$/' file`