# grep starts with capital and appears exactly three times

Tags: regex, unix, grep

I need to grep this: lines that start with a capital and that same capital has to appear EXACTLY 3 times in the line.
E.g. this is a good line :

```
'X^[<*'??X+BXK<:B7#;}V0|<|K!(P|HW}(1O@$JK_}}*.5H"Y&^A)D$QS97R'
```

(starts with X and X appears EXACTLY three times)
I tried this, but apparently the backreferences between the brackets don't work properly:

```
 ^\([A-Z]\)[^\1]*\1[^\1]*\1[^\1]*
```

Why doesn't this work and how should I do it?

Comment: Does that [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33318911/regex-match-everything-except-backreference) help?

Answer (score 0):

In `grep`, you need to use `\(...\)` to create capture groups.  For "starts with a capital and that same letter appears three times", you could do:

```
grep '^\([A-Z]\).*\1.*\1'
```

Comment: yeah i tried that with the \(...\) but it doesnt work either.
the problem is that that letter has to appear EXACTLY three times

Comment: Add `|grep -v '^\([A-Z]\).*\1.*\1.*\1'`

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `awk` for this

```
$ cat ip.txt
Xq2X46Xad
asAnAndA
YeYeYeY
CCC
EsE63Eu6u

$ awk '/^[A-Z]/{c=substr($0,1,1); n=split($0,a,c); if(n==4)print}' ip.txt
Xq2X46Xad
CCC
EsE63Eu6u
```

- `/^[A-Z]/` if line starts with uppercase letter
- `c=substr($0,1,1)` save that letter in a variable
- `n=split($0,a,c)` use that letter to split the line and save number of fields so obtained in `n`
- if there are four fields, then print the line

can be shortened to

```
$ awk '/^[A-Z]/ && split($0,a,substr($0,1,1))==4' ip.txt
$ # or, with GNU awk
$ gawk -v FS= '/^[A-Z]/ && split($0,a,$1)==4' ip.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

`[^\1]` doesn't mean the negation of backreference `\1`.

You have to use negative lookahead, hanchor begin and end, and `-P` option (for PCRE):

```
grep -P '^([A-Z])(?:(?!\1).)*\1(?:(?!\1).)*\1(?:(?!\1).)*$'
```

This will match exactly 3 times in each line the first character if it is a capital

Answer (score 0):

With an awk that splits input into chars when FS is null (e.g. GNU awk):

```
$ awk -F '' '/^[A-Z]/ && gsub($1,"&")==3' file
X^[<*'??X+BXK<:B7#;}V0|<|K!(P|HW}(1O@$JK_}}*.5H"Y&^A)D$QS97R
```

With any awk in any shell on any UNIX box:

```
$ awk '/^[A-Z]/ && gsub(substr($0,1,1),"&")==3' file
X^[<*'??X+BXK<:B7#;}V0|<|K!(P|HW}(1O@$JK_}}*.5H"Y&^A)D$QS97R
```

You might want to change `A-Z` to `[:upper:]` for portability to other locales.