# Mining dictionary for sed search strings

Tags: awk, sed, grep, sh

For fun I was mining the dictionary for words that `sed` could use to modify strings.  Example:

```
sed settee    <<< better
sed statement <<< dated
```

Outputs:

> beer
>   demented

These `sed` `s`words must be at least *5* letters long, and begin with `s`, then another letter, which can appear ***only*** *3* times, with at least one other letter between the first and second instances, and with the third instance as the final letter.

I used `sed` to generate a word list, and it seems to work:

```
d=/usr/share/dict/american-english
sed -n '/^s\([a-z]\)\(.*\1\)\{2\}$/{
            /^s\([a-z]\)\(.*\1\)\{3\}$/!{/^s\([a-z]\)\1/!p}}' $d | 
xargs echo
```

Output:

> sanatoria sanitaria sarcomata savanna secede secrete secretive segregate selective selvedge sentence sentience sentimentalize septette sequence serenade serene serpentine serviceable serviette settee severance severe sewerage sextette stateliest statement stealthiest stoutest straightest straightjacket straitjacket strategist streetlight stretchiest strictest structuralist

But that `sed` code runs three passes through each line, which seems excessively long and kludgy.  How can that code be simplified, while still outputting the same word list?

`grep` or `awk` answers would also be OK.

Comment: you should allow final `g` modifier as well.

Comment: @karakfa, I'd tested for that, but not a *single* word in */usr/share/dict/american-english* meets the spec with an added `g`.  That is `sed -n '/^s\([a-z]\)\(.*\1\)\{2\}[gp]$/{/^s\([a-z]\)\(.*\1\)\{3\}$/!{/^s\([a-z]\)\1[gp]/!p}}' $d |  xargs printf '%s;' ; echo` matches nothing.

Comment: yes, nothing matches from that dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

code is cleaner with `awk` and reads as the spec: split the word based on the second char, three instances of the char will split the word into 4 segments; 2nd one should have at least one char and the last one should be empty.

```
$  awk '/^s/{n=split($1,a,substr($1,2,1)); 
             if(n==4 && length(a[2])>0 && a[4]=="") print}' /usr/share/dict/american-english | xargs
```

> sanatoria sanitaria sarcomata savanna secede secrete secretive
>   segregate selective selvedge sentence sentience sentimentalize
>   septette sequence serenade serene serpentine serviceable serviette
>   settee severance severe sewerage sextette stateliest statement
>   stealthiest stoutest straightest straightjacket straitjacket strategist 
>   streetlight stretchiest strictest structuralist

Answer (score 1):

very cool idea.  I think you're more restrictive than necessary

```
sed -nE '/^s(.)[^\1]+\1[^\1]*\1g?$/p'
```

seems to work fine.  It generated 518 words for me.  I only have `/usr/share/dict/words` dictionary file though.

> sabadilla sabakha sabana sabbatia sabdariffa sacatra saccharilla
>   saccharogalactorrhea saccharorrhea saccharosuria saccharuria sacralgia
>   sacraria sacrcraria sacrocoxalgia sadhaka sadhana sahara saintpaulia
>   salaceta salada salagrama salamandra saltarella salutatoria
>   ...
>   stuntist subbureau sucuriu sucuruju sulphurou surucucu 
>   syenite-porphyry symphyseotomy symphysiotomy symphysotomy symphysy
>   symphytically syndactyly synonymity synonymously synonymy
>   syzygetically syzygy

an interesting find is

```
$ sed snow-nodding <<< now-or-never
noddior-never
```

Comment: This code shares a problem of one of my earlier attempts, (no shown), in that it returns *"sarsaparilla"*, which has *4* *"a"*s, so `sed` would get confused once it hits `rilla`.  `snow-nodding` is great, I had tried scanning for single `s`words ending in `g` but found none in */usr/share/dict/american-english*.

Comment: that's very strange! how come `[^\1]+` matches `\1`? I'm puzzled

Comment: Backreferences aren't handled in character classes, it to `/^s(.).*\1.*\1[gp]*$/{/^s(.).*\1.*\1.*\1/!p}` to only print ones with exactly three, and if there's a word with an s and four p's or g's, well...

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up about the back references, it's not documented, and I wasn't sure why it even worked, or failed to work as expected.  Turns out `[^\1]` matches nothing in the alphabet, and therefore might as well be the same as a `.`.

Comment: Re `/^s(.).*\1.*\1[gp]*$/{/^s(.).*\1.*\1.*\1/!p}`: almost, but that matches `seepage` and `seethe` neither of which works in `sed`, (since there's nothing to replace).

Answer (score 0):

A speedy `pcregrep` method, (*.025 seconds* user time):

```
d=/usr/share/dict/american-english
pcregrep '^s(.)((?!\1).)+\1((?!\1).)*\1$' $d | xargs echo
```

Output:

> sanatoria sanitaria sarcomata savanna secede secrete secretive segregate selective selvedge sentence sentience sentimentalize septette sequence serenade serene serpentine serviceable serviette settee severance severe sewerage sextette stateliest statement stealthiest stoutest straightest straightjacket straitjacket strategist streetlight stretchiest strictest structuralist

---

Code inspired by: [Regex: Match everything except backreference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33318911/regex-match-everything-except-backreference)